# Is it safe to consume microwaved Campbell’s chicken stock?

Tags: food-safety, microwave, frozen, chicken-stock

I often pour a bowl of frozen veggies and a cup of chicken stock (straight from those 1 litre boxes) in a bowl and microwave it for 12 minutes. It comes out fairly hot.

Is this safe to do? Or am I risking food poisoning by not boiling the chicken stock?

Comment: Since this is about a specific product, why don't you ask the company directly instead?

Comment: 12 minutes is a long time in a microwave oven1!!

Comment: @Raditz_35 I selected a specific brand as an example, I realistically use a few but assume they all share the same properties.

Answer (score 3):

Aseptic packaging which is what the Swanson's and anyother brands products in those coated carboard-like packing 9a.K.a Tetrapaks) broth are safe. The aseptic processing has killed thhe harmful bacteria. So long as it was kept refrigerated below 40 deg F after opening it is still safe.

Your frozen veggies if notdefrosted then refrozen are safe.

Combining the two and heating in the microwave in a clean vessel is safe so long as you've not introduced bacteria from another source, your food is as safe as it is going to be.

Comment: Almost correct: “... kept below 40 F for **3-4 days or less**”. After opening, the safety rules for cooked food apply. See our [generic post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer) for details. And you can safely thaw and refreeze food, it’s quality, not safety that will suffer (unless the cumulative time above 40F gets too large).